# 'as much as' VS 'more than'

Tags: comparatives, cloze-test

Please, help me. I am so confused with my English task.

> Very few books are read ___ Harry Potter by children.
>   a) as much as
>   b) more than
>   c) the most

> Very few channels are watched by children ____ the Cartoon Channel.
>   a) as much as
>   b) more than
>   c) the most

I can't decide if it's 'as much as' or 'more than'.
I would like some advice. What do you think?

Comment: I think you need a basic review of much, more and most as adverbial comparisons here and they are all different.

Comment: I think you need to start reading better tests.  Those are atrocious.

Answer (score 1):

> Very [few books] are read ___ [Harry Potter]; by children

The logical choice, in my opinion would be to use b) *more than*, than a) *as much as*.

My reasoning for this is that ***more*** is the irregular comparative of the base adjective *much* and since the base adjective *few* is already used, another base adjective can’t be used in the same sentence:

> Very *few* books are read as *much* as Harry Potter; by children.

Therefore, since it is a comparative sentence, it would make much more sense if it was:

> Very *few* books are read ***more*** *than* Harry Potter by children.
>
> Very *few* channels are watched by children ***more*** *than* the Cartoon Channel.

While the latter sentence, does sound odd, so does [*as much as*/*the most* the Cartoon Channel]. But I could be wrong, this is just my take on this.

Source: https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/comparative-and-superlative/

Comment: Very few books are read by children as much as the Harry Potter books.

Comment: @Lambie I know it makes semantic sense, but grammar wise, I was suggesting why it could be an issue. So am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, the issue is that read by children needs to stay together. Very few books are read by children more than Harry Potter   [books]. Gosh, it can make one's head spin. :)

Comment: @Lambie Oh I was just using what the OP gave, from what looks like an exam question. :) Why would it be worded wrong? And I don't see the problem with having by children at the end, though one can question its importance in the sentence as it looks more like a subordinate clause)

Comment: Aha, good, yes. Call me a dodo. :) I hate answering questions from tests. So unfair. :)